# App Crashed on BackPressed 3rd of 4th time

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am facing a strange issue in my android app and I am not able to figure it out. Is there anyone who can help me regarding this issue.

Let me describe about my app and issue.

I am getting all the images from gallery and displaying them on a gridview using adapter. Once displayed, I am sending an image from this gridview of Activity A to next activity on click of gridview item and assigning this image on an image view in Activity B... When I come back from Activity B to Activity A on pressing Bsck button, it works fine. But when I repeat this process three to four times, app is crashing. I don't know what is the issue. I am sure that the issue is in Activity A..

Here is the code of Activity A....

```
package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import android.content.Intent; 
import android.database.Cursor; 
import android.net.Uri; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.provider.MediaStore; 
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; 
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks; 
import android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader; 
import android.support.v4.content.Loader; 
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter; 
import android.view.LayoutInflater; 
import android.view.View; 
import android.view.ViewGroup; 
import android.widget.AdapterView; 
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener; 
import android.widget.GridView;

public class ImageLoader extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    GridView gridView;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;       
    Cursor cursor;
    Uri uri;
    String ID;
    Intent intent;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.videos, container, false);
        gridView = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(null);
        mAdapter = null;
        cursor = null;
        uri = null;
        ID = null;
        intent = null;
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.gridview_item1,
            null,
            new String[] { "_data","_id"} ,
            new int[] { R.id.video_thumbnail_imageview},
            0
        );

        /** Setting adapter for the gridview */
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        /** Loader to get images from the SD Card */
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                cursor = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                ID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("image_id"));
                intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Testing_Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Image_Path",ID);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        /** Getting uri to the Thumbnail images stored in the external storage */
        uri = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

        /** Invoking the uri */
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), uri, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /** A callback method, invoked after the requested content provider  returned all the data */
    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please post the crash logs. They would help a lot.

Comment: is `onCreateView` called each time the back button is pressed ? if so, i suspect outofmemory error

Comment: Here is the screenshot of logcat : (http://1drv.ms/1EmFtaK)

Comment: @mangusta Yes of course I think we have to call onCreateView everytime.

Comment: @AlexHales try closing `cursor` before calling activity B

Comment: @mangusta I done the same thing "closing cursor before calling activity B" , but still getting same issue.

Comment: @AlexHales how have you done it? post your modified code plz